# Как передать сразу несколько комманд на Android Box?

Tags: android, клавиатура, key

Приветствую ! При нажатии на кнопку DEL удаляется один символ, а при удержании кнопки DEL должен удаляится весь текст, но удаляется опять так и только один символ.

Тут я создаю команду для удаления (69 - это команда DEL):

```
Key mKey = new Key(RemoteIME.mService, 0, 69);
sendCmdMessage(SendThread.CMD_SEND_KEY, event.getAction(), 0, mKey);
```

А это метод для передачи команды на Android Box:

```
private void sendCmdMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj) {
    if( mSendCmdHandler != null ) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.arg2 = arg2;
        msg.obj = obj;
        mSendCmdHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    else {
        mSendCmdHandler = mSendThread.getHandler();
        Log.d(TAG, "mSendCmdHandler is null!");
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что даже при многократнои передачи комманды она всё равно её понимает как одну, то есть удаляет только один символ.

Прошу помогите разобраться. Заранее спасибо !